# Java swing jLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

I have an code that adds jbutton on the clicked place in the jLayeredpane on mouse click. Now the problem is on resize. When i dont change the size of jLayeredpane on runtime there is no problem. When i maximize the window and i have made it as, the jLayeredpane will adjust to fit the screen so when i add a button on the jpane now and when the window size is reduced the buttons i have added is out of range and so it is not displayed. Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article [*Laying Out Components in a Layered Pane*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html#layout) mentions, "Although a layered pane has no layout manager by default, you can still assign a layout manager to the layered pane."

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. Use [Layouts](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html#layout) :)